# Can't get scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator to work

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate scatter data on a 2D-grid but can't seem to get the RBF-function to work. I get error messages about my input and no output.

I'm new to Python in general and the meshgrid function is a bit confusing to me as well so there might be issues with my usage in that area too.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RBFInterpolator
import numpy as np
import json

def main():

    file_path="C:/rawdata/"
    files=os.listdir(file_path)

    for filename in files:
        #open file and load data
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
            jfile=open(file_path+filename, 'r')
            global jdata
            jdata=json.load(jfile)

            #get meta data
            width_m=int(round(float(jdata["WidthMm"])/1000))
            length_m=int(round(float(jdata["LengthM"])))

            #create empty lists           
            x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
            y=[]
            z=[]

            #populate lists
            for items in jdata["OnlineScans"]:                                                  
                type_str=items["Type"]

                if type_str!="Weight":
                    continue

                for keys in items["Scans"]:
                    y_point=int(round(float(keys)))
                    y.append(y_point)

                    for r in items["Scans"][keys]:
                        z.append(int(round(float(r))))

    #printer(x,y,z)
    interpol(x,y,z,length_m,width_m)


#interpolate data on the total surface (length x width)
#store interpolated data in new array
def interpol(x,y,z,length_m,width_m):
    
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    rbf = RBFInterpolator(x, y, z)
    Z = rbf(X, Y)

    plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def printer(x,y,z):
    
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    plt.scatter(X,Y)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

main()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Depending on the input I give I get error messages such as:

Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate_rbfinterp.py", line 293, in **init**
raise ValueError("`y` must be a 2-dimensional array.")
ValueError: `y` must be a 2-dimensional array.